# "Select which app to use by default" isn't showing up in the app chooser

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#StartActivity) it is shown how to provide a default option when starting an intent. But I can't see a difference to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser), except in one case `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` is used and `Intent.ACTION_SEND` in the other. This is my code:

```
Context context = Forms.Context;

var filePath = new File(filename);
var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(filePath);
string mimeType = Util.Helper.GetMIMEType(filename);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);

context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Furthermore, I read that `Intent.createChooser` doesn't provide a default option, so I removed that, but still no success. The other tips here on SO also didn't help (e.g. use `startActivityForResult()`).

Is this a setting on the tablet? I'm on Android 5.1.1.

**Edit**

Now I tried the suggestion from [Elvis Xia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5610850/elvis-xia-msft):

```
Context context = Forms.Context;

var filePath = new File(filename);
var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(filePath);
string mimeType = Util.Helper.GetMIMEType(filename);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);
intent.SetType(mimeType);

context.StartActivity(intent);
```

The file isn't opened. Instead I get a toast like message with

> Could not obtain the file name!

`fileUri` for example is `file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/SomeApp/TempDocs/57761.7Z`
`mimeType` is `application/x-7z-compressed`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the "“Select which app to use by default” isn't showing up in the app chooser" part:

If you start with `context.StartActivity(intent);` android manages the default handling and stores the user-selected-default in the apps local data. There is no api that your app can use to manipulate the "standard selelection"

If you use `Intent.createChooser(...)` there is no default mechanism. You always get the chooser.

To find out how intents work you can use the android open source app [intent-intercept](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept) available in [fdroid app store](https://f-droid.org/app/uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept)

Comment: So when is the default checkbox shown if Android manages that? Is there a possibility to clean the stored selections? Perhaps thats the reason the default checkbox isn't displayed?

Comment: with `context.StartActivity(intent);` Once the user has chosen the default for an app the chooser is not shown any more.

Comment: I tried to clear the chosen apps in the settings app for my application, but there wasn't something to clear (button was disabled and a notice was shown, where no default apps are defined). If you open the file multiple times he remembers your choice after the second or third call and it will open it like a default app (but there is no checkbox or something like that). Don't know wyh it behaves like so, but it seems there is no solution for sending files ... Perhaps the Samsung UI is doing something differently.

Answer (score 0):

From your codes, you are trying to create a file and send/share it through [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). The problem is:files can not be shared directly  by `Intent`. If you want to achieve that, you will have to store the file on the device as pre-work and share it using following :

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(exportPath));
```

Notes:`exportPath` uses `file://xxx.xx` schema.

If the data you want to send is not of a huge quantity, it is strongly recommended that you send the data directly instead of a file.

Update: To create a file in Android, you need to call `file.createNewFile();`:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
file.CreateNewFile();
if (file.Exists())
{
     var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
     string mimeType = Util.Helper.GetMIMEType(filename);

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
     intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);
     intent.SetType(mimeType);

     context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I stored a file on the device and now I want to open it with an external app. Therefore I tried your approach with `intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);`. Through `Android.Net.Uri.FromFile()` I get the correct schema (`file://xxx.xx`). As result I now get a ton of options, where many of them are not able to handle the file ... In addition, there is still no default check box. What do you mean with *send the data directly* exactly?

Comment: You can filter the possible target apps by setting the mimeType (like the codes in your question). By "send the data directly",  I mean, if the file contains not so much data, then share the content of this file. ex: share string of a `txt` file, share the `byte[]` of an image.

Comment: Ok, now I added the mime type. I edited my question to show you my current approach. Currently I get an error, where the filename could not be obtained ... Is `Intent.ActionView` correct?

Comment: To create a new file in android system, you need to call `file.createNewFile`. Please check my updates. And please use `Intent.ActionSend`.

Comment: Through `Intent.ActionSend` I get sharing options like through mail, dropbox, ... I have some apps installed, which could handle the zip/7z file, but they aren't showing up. Still no default option.